# azure-cognitiveservices-speech api error while using with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, azure-devops, docker-image, azure-speech

I am trying to use Microsoft speech to text api(azure-cognitiveservices-speech) in AWS Lambda. In AWS Lambda I am using docker image(public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8). when I run the the code I am getting the following error:

```
Speech Recognition canceled: CancellationReason.Error
Error details: Runtime error: Failed to initialize platform (azure-c-shared)
```

I tried to solve issue by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk?tabs=linux%2Crhel-centos%2Cios-xcode%2Cmac-xcode%2Candroid-studio#get-the-speech-sdk
But still getting the same error

Comment: I am getting the same "Failed to initialize platform (azure-c-shared)" in AWS on EC2 on Amazon Linux starting with versions of 1.19 of the Azure Speech SDK. I also followed all the steps to configure for Linux. Couple of notes:
<br/>
1. versions of SDK <= 1.18 didn't have to configure anything extra and had no such errors
2. versions of SDK >= 1.19 work for me locally on Mac OS just fine without any extra configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using ubuntu base customer docker image. The issue was with lambda docker base image as this does not support Azure SKD(azure-cognitiveservices-speech). So I use custom docker image. For ref I am sharing GitHub link of my custom docker image - Github [1](https://github.com/Ravisiswaliya/azure_speech_to_text_with_aws_lambda)https://github.com/Ravisiswaliya/azure_speech_to_text_with_aws_lambda